# rspec not accepting custom http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My spec is like so:

```
describe SomeController do

    before(:each) do
        @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'
    end

    describe 'GET #index' do
        it "returns response" do
            get 'index', format: :m3u8
            puts response.code # prints 406
            response.should be_success # fails
        end
    end
end
```

The controller:

```
class SomeController < AuthenticatedController
  def index
    Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl", :m3u8
    # do some stuff
    respond_to do |format|
        format.m3u8 { render :m3u8 => @some_variable.html_safe }
    end
end
```

What am I missing to get it to respond with status 200?  Right now, the status returned is 406.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `@`.

```
before(:each) do
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'
end
```